# Center image and text without gap

Tags: html, css

I have 2 blocks with the image and text. I need to center all of them vertically and horizontally.
I use flexbox, but when the text is longer - between image and text appears padding.
How to remove this padding [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWrl3.png)

```css
.product-teaser {
  width: 235px;
  height: 340px;
  margin: 10px;
}
img {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.product-teaser-stock {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 17px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Another simple example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="product-teaser">
    <div class="product-teaser-stock product-teaser-stock-undefined date-available" style="color:#009900;">
    <img class="free-shipping-icon" width="30" src="https://shop.dev.pictureserver.net/images/pic/70/3c/undef_src_shop_shop_id_1_type_shipping_image.png" alt="" title="">
    <span class="stock_title">FREE shipping, available from 03.02.2021</span>
  </div>
  <div class="product-teaser">
      <div class="product-teaser-stock product-teaser-stock-undefined date-available" style="color:#009900;">
      <img class="free-shipping-icon" width="30" src="https://shop.dev.pictureserver.net/images/pic/70/3c/undef_src_shop_shop_id_1_type_shipping_image.png" alt="" title="">
      <span class="stock_title">FREE shipping</span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the padding?

Comment: it is not a real padding - this gap

Comment: okay and also you want to center them

Comment: yes, I need to center them without this gap https://prnt.sc/zubczm

Comment: hey @katerina you are using margin in your product-teaser try removing it  and align them at the center  then restyle

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: no, I have added width to the text, but it is not perfect decision

Answer (score 0):

This is because you center your text. If you align your text to the left, you will have the same padding between the elements.

Setting `word-break: break-all` to the `stock_title` illustrates this problem even more.

So as a solution I would either suggest either aligning the text to the left. Or set a width that breaks your text so that a whole line fits into the width of the container. This is really hard to do and won't be "responsive" since it will only work for a specific font size and won't really scale.

Or you can update your design, and put the "available from" text in a complete new line, so that the "free shipping" always looks the same together with the image

```css
.product-teaser {
  width: 235px;
  height: 340px;
  margin: 10px;
}

img {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.product-teaser-stock {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-teaser">
  <div class="product-teaser-stock product-teaser-stock-undefined date-available" style="color:#009900;">
    <img class="free-shipping-icon" width="30" src="https://shop.dev.pictureserver.net/images/pic/70/3c/undef_src_shop_shop_id_1_type_shipping_image.png" alt="" title="" />
    <span class="stock_title">FREE shipping</span>
  </div>
  <span style="color:#009900;" class="product-teaser-stock"> available from 2.2.2020</span>
</div>
<div class="product-teaser">
  <div class="product-teaser-stock product-teaser-stock-undefined date-available" style="color:#009900;">
    <img class="free-shipping-icon" width="30" src="https://shop.dev.pictureserver.net/images/pic/70/3c/undef_src_shop_shop_id_1_type_shipping_image.png" alt="" title="" />
    <span class="stock_title">FREE shipping</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you set a 'text-align center', also if you wanna center both images it's better to set the parent to flex as well, something like this:

```
.product-teaser {
    width: 235px;
    height: 340px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
img {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.product-teaser-stock {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
    max-height: 17px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you want to let the text that is in the first div of product-teaser `.product-teaser`.

I would suggest you take a block with the class of stock_title `.stock_title` to align the text to the left to avoid the gap between the image and the left.

I guess this code would help

```
.stock_title {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: yes, but my block will not center <https://prnt.sc/zudten>